# Exclude results in find_closest (Tkinter, Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a script to store movements over a hexgrid using Tkinter. As part of this I want to use a mouse-click on a Tkinter canvas to first identify the click location, and then draw a line between this point and the location previously clicked.

Generally this works, except that after I've drawn a line, it become an object that qualifies for future calls off the find_closest method. This means I can still draw lines between points, but selecting the underlying Hex in the Hexgrid over times becomes nearly impossible. I was wondering if someone could help me find a solution to exclude particular objects (lines) from the find_closest method.

edit: I hope this code example is minimal enough.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from math import radians, cos, sin, sqrt


class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

        self.c1 = Canvas(self.parent, width=int(1.5*340), height=int(1.5*270), bg='white')
        self.c1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.clickcount = 0
        self.clicks = [(0,0)]
        self.startx = int(20*1.5)
        self.starty = int(20*1.5)
        self.radius = int(20*1.5)  # length of a side
        self.hexagons = []
        self.columns = 10
        self.initGrid(self.startx, self.starty, self.radius, self.columns)
        self.c1.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)

    def initGrid(self, x, y, radius, cols):
        """
        2d grid of hexagons
        """
        radius = radius
        column = 0
        for j in range(cols):
            startx = x
            starty = y
            for i in range(6):
                breadth = column * (1.5 * radius)
                if column % 2 == 0:
                    offset = 0
                else:
                    offset = radius * sqrt(3) / 2

                self.draw(startx + breadth, starty + offset, radius)
                starty = starty + 2 * (radius * sqrt(3) / 2)

            column = column + 1

    def draw(self, x, y, radius):
        start_x = x
        start_y = y
        angle = 60
        coords = []
        for i in range(6):
            end_x = start_x + radius * cos(radians(angle * i))
            end_y = start_y + radius * sin(radians(angle * i))
            coords.append([start_x, start_y])
            start_x = end_x
            start_y = end_y

        hex = self.c1.create_polygon(coords[0][0], coords[0][1], coords[1][0], coords[1][1], coords[2][0],
                                        coords[2][1], coords[3][0], coords[3][1], coords[4][0], coords[4][1],
                                        coords[5][0], coords[5][1], fill='black')
        self.hexagons.append(hex)

    def click(self, evt):
        self.clickcount = self.clickcount + 1
        x, y = evt.x, evt.y
        tuple_alfa = (evt.x, evt.y)
        self.clicks.append(tuple_alfa)

        if self.clickcount >= 2:
            start = self.clicks[self.clickcount - 1]
            startx = start[0]
            starty = start[1]
            self.c1.create_line(evt.x, evt.y, startx, starty, fill='white')
        clicked = self.c1.find_closest(x, y)[0]
        print(clicked)


root = tkinter.Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could maybe check if `clicked` is same as the line created and if it is, then temporarily disable it and then check for the closest again.

Comment: I don't know what your GUI looks like, so maybe this would not look good, but you could use `.tag_lower(<id of the newly created line>)` to keep the lines behind the grid vertices.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @BryanOakley edited with minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Is `setBackground` truly necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Apologies, I have removed some other superfluous code. I hope this is better.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"selecting the underlying Hex in the Hexgrid over times becomes nearly impossible"_? Why does it become impossible? Can your example code show why it is impossible?

Comment: If the if statement in the click function is removed the script works: when clicked it returns a number associated with the clicked hex. However, when the if statement is included, so to draw a line between points clicked on the canvas, the find_closest method not only starts finding new points (the lines), but also finds points not even close to where the click occurred. As to why, to the best of my ability, I have no idea.